# Routing getIcon missing from api v 2.5.4

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am working with the here maps api doing some routing between two points.

I can calculate the route and show the maneuvers to the user but I cannot get the maneuver icon. In the previous api, there was a javascript function getIcon, but that has been removed from the most resent api (2.5.4).

When I take a look at here.com and perform the routing between the two points, I can find the js function in there, but the function is not in the 2.5.4 version of the api.

(I cannot upgrade to v 3 of the api at this point in time, so I don't know if that will help)

What can I do when using v2.5.4 of the api to get the maneuver icon to show it to my users?

Below is a sample screen snip from here.com on the images I am referring to.

[image: maneuver_image_sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Turn symbols are not part of the API, you can use in the Maneuvers the "direction" and "action" properties to draw your own symbols.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I eventually opted to not include the turn symbols. It turns out that with the initial implementation we had, we got access to an internal api which wasn't available publically. It works with the turn symbols just as good.

Answer (score 0):

Was this ever exposed in the API?

Just looked through the compressed code and I don't find that symbol anywhere...

Anyways, I believe the last resort is to map the "action" property in the maneuvers to your own images (or an image sprite similar to the one on here.com ;). The possible values of the action property are documented here:

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-enumerations.html#resource-type-enumerations__enum-private-transport-action-type